# With TSQL, How do I insert NEW record in Table2 from existing record in Table1 and generate NEWID

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Table1 contains Work Orders and Table2 contains Installers. I would like to insert a record into Table2 for Work Order 3906 in Table1.  Tables are indexed such that Table1GUID = Table2GUID. Currently Table1GUID is NULL for 3906 because there is no corresponding record in Table2 so I'm guessing that I need to generate NEWID()  for Table1GUID and then insert new record in Table2 such that records from both tables have same GUID?

Below is throwing error Msg 547 UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. How do I create NEWID in Table1 and Insert into Table2?

```
UPDATE Document SET Table1GUID = NEWID() WHERE WONumber = '3906'
```

Which of the 2 below is best for creating record in Table2?

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Table2GUID)
SELECT Table1GUID FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.WOnumber = '3906'
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Table2GUID)
SELECT Table1GUID FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2GUID = Table1GUID
WHERE Table1.WOnumber = '3906'
```

Comment: We don't know what your foreign key structures so it is hard to say for sure. But the second one you posted doesn't make any sense at all. You are inserting to Table2 so joining to it wouldn't work as you haven't yet created the row. Not being clear what you are trying to do you might also look at the OUTPUT clause. I suspect that is probably what you want.

Comment: Record exists in Table1 (work order 3096) but it hasn't been assigned an installer (Table2).  I need to create a new record in Table2 that is linked (i.e. same GUID) to record in Table1 for work order 3906

Comment: If this needs to be done at the time you insert into Table1 I would suggest using OUTPUT. If it needs to be done later then you can use a query to get the value of the guid from Table1 (your first example). Does that help?

Comment: My question is how do I create a new record in Table2 that is linked to an existing record in Table1 where Table1GUID is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Since column stores `NULL` and you **don't** have corresponding row in `Table2` joining has no sense. Try add a filter predicate you already mentioned and replace `NULL` value with `newid()`:

```
set @new_id = newid()

INSERT INTO Table2 (Table2GUID)
SELECT @new_id
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.WOnumber = '3906'
  and t1.Table1GUID is NULL

UPDATE t1 SET
  Table1GUID = @new_id
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.WOnumber = '3906'
  and t1.Table1GUID is NULL
```

if these changes haveto be multirecord you will need some other approach